# deleting line from figure in bokeh

Tags: python, user-interface, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh. I made a widget where when I click a checkbox I want to be able to add/delete a line in a bokeh figure. I have 20 such checkboxes and I dont want to replot the whole figure, just to delete 1 line if a checkbox was unchecked.

This is done through a callback, where I have access to the figure object. I would imagine there is a way to do something like this:

```
F=figure()
F.line('x', 'y', source=source, name='line1')
F.line('x', 'z', source=source, name='line2')

%%in callback
selected_line_name = 'line1' # this would be determined by checkbox
selected_line = F.children[selected_line_name]
delete(selected_line)
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to
1) access a glyph from its parent object
2) delete a glyph

I tried setting the datasource 'y'=[], but since all column data sources have to be the same size, this removes all the plots...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways:

```
# Keep the glyphs in a variable:
line2 = F.line('x', 'z', source=source, name='line2')

# or get the glyph from the Figure:
line2 = F.select_one({'name': 'line2'})

# in callback:
line2.visible = False
```

Comment: thanks @Alex, this is great! Is there a way to not just hide the line (which I presume keeps it in memory and slows down the system), but to completely delete it?

Comment: I guess this: `F.renderers.remove(line2)` (renderers behaves as a list so you manipulate it as any python list) but I would imagine that the optimization is minimal as your data will still be stored in source. So that would save only on bokeh not having to parse that glyph and checking its visibility. Never profiled it, though and not familiar enough with the internals to say with any certainty. If you do profile it, let us know!

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to delete all the lines on a graph automatically, or to reset it?

Comment: There is not. We could consider adding API for that but honestly it's probably just as simple and effective to create a new plot at that point.

Comment: @bigreddot is there an easy way to delete a bokeh plot?

Comment: Just replace it or delete it from the layout children like any object from a python list, e.g. https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter/main.py#L59

Answer (score 9):

This will work to maintain a shared 'x' data source column if glyphs are assigned as a variable and given a name attribute.  The remove function fills the appropriate 'y' columns with nans, and the restore function replaces nans with the original values.

The functions require numpy and bokeh GlyphRenderer imports.  I'm not sure that this method is worthwhile given the simple visible on/off option, but I am posting it anyway just in case this helps in some other use case.

Glyphs to remove or restore are referenced by glyph name(s), contained within a list.

```
src_dict = source.data.copy()

def remove_glyphs(figure, glyph_name_list):
    renderers = figure.select(dict(type=GlyphRenderer))
    for r in renderers:
        if r.name in glyph_name_list:
            col = r.glyph.y
            r.data_source.data[col] = [np.nan] * len(r.data_source.data[col])

def restore_glyphs(figure, src_dict, glyph_name_list):
    renderers = figure.select(dict(type=GlyphRenderer))
    for r in renderers:
        if r.name in glyph_name_list:
            col = r.glyph.y
            r.data_source.data[col] = src_dict[col]
```

Example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Range1d, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer

import numpy as np

output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=200, plot_height=150,
           x_range=Range1d(0, 6),
           y_range=Range1d(0, 10),
           toolbar_location=None)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[1, 3, 5],
                                    y1=[1, 1, 2],
                                    y2=[1, 2, 6],
                                    y3=[1, 3, 9]))

src_dict = source.data.copy()

line1 = p.line('x', 'y1',
               source=source,
               color='blue',
               name='g1',
               line_width=3)

line2 = p.line('x', 'y2',
               source=source,
               color='red',
               name='g2',
               line_width=3)

line3 = p.line('x', 'y3',
               source=source,
               color='green',
               name='g3',
               line_width=3)
print(source.data)
show(p)
```

out:

```
{'x': [1, 3, 5], 'y1': [1, 1, 2], 'y2': [1, 2, 6], 'y3': [1, 3, 9]}
```

[image]

```
remove_glyphs(p, ['g1', 'g2'])
print(source.data)
show(p)
```

out:

```
{'x': [1, 3, 5], 'y1': [nan, nan, nan], 'y2': [nan, nan, nan], 'y3': [1, 3, 9]}
```

[image]

```
restore_glyphs(p, src_dict, ['g1', 'g3'])
print(source.data)
show(p)
```

('g3' was already on the plot, and is not affected)

out:

```
{'x': [1, 3, 5], 'y1': [1, 1, 2], 'y2': [nan, nan, nan], 'y3': [1, 3, 9]}
```

[image]

```
restore_glyphs(p, src_dict, ['g2'])
print(source.data)
show(p)
```

out:

```
{'x': [1, 3, 5], 'y1': [1, 1, 2], 'y2': [1, 2, 6], 'y3': [1, 3, 9]}
```

[image]